# How many states in a ring counter having 5 flip-flops?

Tags: flipflop

I am new in digital logic design but have a great curiosity about it. I want to make a ring counter with 5 flip-flops, but I am not sure how many states are possible with that many?

Comment: Question for those who down-voted this question: Is this not a legitimate question?  Yes: a quick Google search would have lead the Original Poster to the answer (Wikipedia or other site) but the great advantage of **THIS** site is that there is such a collection of knowledge here that this site seems like a logical starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Using 5 flip flops to create a ring counter will result in 5 states. See the [ring counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_counter) article on Wikipedia for information on how one works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good answer to this question.  5 Flip-flops can build a state machine with 2^5 states.  Yes, you can easily build a 5-bit ring counter with 5 flip flops, and that's how its usually done, but by definition it is possible to build a 5-bit ring counter with fewer flip flops, and a higher-bit ring counter with 5 flip flops.

So, the answer:  You can build a state machine with 2^5 states using 5 flip flops.  You NEED 5 states to build a 5-bit ring counter, but you can mathematically use more states than the minimum.  You SHOULD be able to design a 5-bit ring counter with three flip flops.

Answer (score -1):

5^2. Simple exponential based on how many flipyflopies, and how many states each flipflop has.

Comment: This is incorrect. A ring counter is not the same as a counter. The correct answer is 5 states. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter

Comment: 5^2 is also wrong for counters. The correct number of states for a normal counter would be 2^5.

Comment: thanks. I have one more query. Why flip-flop is known as latch?

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan - Because whenever it's in one of the flip-flopped states, it stays there. E.g. it's "latched" into that state.